# Searching comma separated database field in Laravel and show details with greater than 4 matching numbers

Tags: php, laravel

I have numbers stored as comma separated in the database field e.g ticketNumbers:1,2,3,12,45,67. The user has a textbox in laravel blade where he/she enters the 6 numbers to search people with those numbers. Now in my blade l want to only retrieve people that have more than 4 numbers that are similar to the searched numbers. Below is the function in my controller to search but its showing everyone even with one number matched.

```
public function findPerson(Request $request)
{

    $s = $request->search;
    $s1 = $request->search1;
    $s2 = $request->search2;
    $s3 = $request->search3;
    $s4 = $request->search4;
    $s5 = $request->search5;

    $fac = $s.','.$s1.','.$s2.','.$s3.','.$s4.','.$s5;

    $data = explode(',',$fac);
    $str='';
    $i=1; // to append AND in query

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
      $str .= 'FIND_IN_SET("'.$value.'" ,ticketNumbers)';
      if($i < count($data)){
        $str .=' OR '; // use OR as per use
      }
      $i++;

    }

      $raffles = Raffle::whereRaw($str)->get();

     return View('raffles.index', compact('raffles'));
}
```

Below is the screenshot of my blade view

[My laravel blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lflzi.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad